# Gitlab CE has no Layout

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-7

I have a problem with my Gitlab. After the installation  it has no Layout. 
When i try

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

It outputs

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Gitlab is running on Debian with Apache. nginx is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

from your directory run the following command

```
bundle install
```

if you see permission error the try above with command by appending "sudo"

You need to install rails app first then you can compile it's assets.

Comment: still comes  Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
 and when trying gem install rails comes     No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/opt/gitlab/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/cache/i18n-0.7.0.gem